# Can I use the same function in different ASP.NET pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, class-library

```
protected void DropDownMainProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mainProductCode = DropDownMainProduct.SelectedValue;

    if (mainProductCode == "0")
    {
        DropDownSubProduct.SelectedValue = "0";
        DropDownSubProduct.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
    }
    else
    {
        DropDownSubProduct.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
    }
}
```

Can I use the `DropDownMainProduct_SelectedIndexChanged` function in different ASP.NET pages without re-writing the dropdown's `IndexChanged` method?

Comment: No, it's specific to the `Page` class it belongs to.

Comment: ...but why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: `DropDownSubProduct.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");` <-- This will not work. HTML's `disabled` attribute does not have `true`/`false` values: that's not how boolean HTML attributes work.

Comment: `DropDownSubProduct.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");` This is still working 

Comment: @ErandaMaduasanka boolean HTML attributes, like [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled), ignore the value: setting it to "false" would also *disable* the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to accomplish this. This might help.

You want to re-use `DropDownMainProduct_SelectedIndexChanged` on other pages. That method interacts with another drop-down, `DropDownSubProduct`. This implies that you're going to have both drop-downs on both pages.

A *user control* allows you to define your own control which contains multiple controls. The user control has its own code-behind with event handlers for the controls it contains.

So instead of trying to figure out how to re-use the event handlers, you can just put both drop-downs and their event handlers in a user control and re-use that on multiple pages.

- Right-click on your project, "Add new item," and add a Web Forms User Control. You can call it "MyDropDowns.ascx".
- Add both of your drop-downs to that user control.
- Add the event handlers for the drop-downs to the user control just like you would with a web form. It's like a WebForm within a W

Now you've got a new file - MyDropDowns.ascx (or whatever you called it) in your project. The next step is to add it to your web form.

Beneath the page directive, add a registration for your user control.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MyDropDowns" 
    Src="~/MyDropDowns.ascx" %>
```

"uc" is just a common convention - it indicates that the tag represents a user control.

Now you can add the control to your WebForm like any other control. You can even add more than one to the same page.

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc:MyDropDowns ID="MyDropDowns1" runat="server" />
        <uc:MyDropDowns ID="MyDropDowns2" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

If your WebForm needs to get values from the user control, you can add properties to the user control's code behind, like

```cs
public string MainProductSelectedValue()
{
    return DropDownMainProduct.SelectedValue;
}
```

...and then the WebForm can read those properties just like it reads the properties of other server controls:

```cs
var productSelectedValue = MyDropDowns1.MainProductSelectedValue()
```

You can also add public methods and events to the user control so that the WebForm can interact with the user control or respond to its events.

Here is [some more documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.100)).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can have each page call your "general" routines page, and thus you only have one copy of that code.

```
   protected void DropDownMainProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         MyCode.MyDropDown(sender);
    }
```

And in your project wide project, then this:

```
public static class MyCode
{

    static void MyDropDownRoutine(Object ctl)
    {
        DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)ctl;

        string mainProductCode = dl.SelectedValue;

        if (mainProductCode == "0")
        {
            dl.SelectedValue = "0";
            dl.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
        }
        else
        {
            dl.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
        }
    }
}
```

So, yes, the code routine can be called and used by all pages.

But, you STILL have to place that dd in each page, you STILL have to set the datatext/datavalue fields, and you STILL need that code routine.

Why not build a user control, and then you can drag/drop that same control into each page, and thus you ONLY EVER have one copy of the markup, the code, and the one event?

Comment: I typed my whole answer and only then noticed you had mentioned using a user control. Oh well.

Comment: Well, you more than noticed - you also took time to write out a rather nice answer explaining and suggesting a UC with example - upvoted.